# How to reset/clear ckeditor when I clicked a button?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

Hi I'm trying to clear ckeditor by means of clicking the reset button. So far, I can't construct the code and I refer to internet for solutions but, unfortunately got no any good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below statement:

CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaId.setData('');

Here 'textAreaId' will be the id of textArea that has been replaced by ckEditor.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that one but I don't know where should I put it.

Comment: you can put it in click event of button. If possible, you can share your code, so It can be checked, where you are going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I've tried the onlick function also but, it didn't work.But here's what I did yesterday:
        function dothis(){
        CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaId.setData('');
        }
              <input type ="reset"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-top:3%;" onclick="dothis()"  >